# How to draw such boxes in Netron?

Tags: graphics, output-formatting, grid-layouts

How to draw a box like this:

[image]

This was drawn by https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron

---

**My attempt:**

```
conv = ConvolutionLayer[64, {3, 3}, "Input" -> {3, 40, 30}];
Grid[{{
    Style["Convolution", White, Background -> RGBColor[{51, 85, 136} / 255]],
    Style["Weights", Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.7]],
    Style["Biases", Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.7]]
}, {Column[{
    "Input" -> StringRiffle[NetExtract[conv, "Input"], "*"],
    "Output" -> StringRiffle[NetExtract[conv, "Output"], "*"]
}], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}}, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left
]
```

Some problem:

`Style[..., Background -> ...]` can't fill the entire grid.

`Grid` seems no way to use rounded rectangles.

Comment: You can use `Item` to set grid's items background. I'd forget about round corners because only `Framed` or `Rectangle` support them, and you can't set it for a single corner. And if you wrap entire grid with `Framed` it will be a pain to get items backgrounds aligned with rounded `Framed`.

Comment: You can also use try a setup with nine-patch images. They'd certainly work. Might not be easy to get nice though.